# What is correct? If Bob was a girl (he / she) would run

Tags: grammatical-gender

The gender of the subject is masculine but the situation is that the subject is feminine. What should the pronoun be?

Comment: Are you asking about "regular" English or gender identity English?  In regular English, you're still talking about Bob and his actual gender doesn't change, so it would be "he".  In gender identity English, it would be the gender-neutral "they", regardless of the actual or hypothetical situation, although Bob would be free to refer to himself as "she".  Now if you'll excuse me, my brain is going to explode.  :-)

Comment: @Cascabel - If Bruce Jenner had been a girl, could (he/she) have run in the Olympics?

Comment: @Jim Does not fit the (mixed?) (unreal present ?) conditional posited. Still unclear. If you can reword this to work in the context have a go at it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am talking about the type of English that most English speakers would understand. I guess that is "regular" English. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the hypothetical situation such as "If Bob were a girl he/she would run with his/her hips and elbows swinging"; or is it more like a real-life situation like "If Bob were a girl that knock in the groin would not hurt him so much"? Or sumpin like that?

Comment: @Cascabel the former

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English. You would have the exact same question if the sentence were in German or Russian.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Not if it was in Turkish, so I think it's still about English (and some other languages, but that's beside the point). By this, I mean that Turkish doesn't have gender-specific nouns (like he or she; of course we have stuff like man and woman), so it wouldn't ever become a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of different examples to this situation. Would you be using *it* instead of *he* if Bob suddenly became an animal or an inanimate object?

> If Bob was a lion **he** would jump.
>
> If Bob was a ship **he** wouldn't sink so easily.

The reason for this is that our subject is still *Bob the human* and not *Bob the lion* or *Bob the ship*. With those examples in mind, this problem becomes easier to address:

> If Bob was a girl **he** would run.

Again, our subject is *Bob the male person* and not *Bob the female person*, so we should still use *he* as that is the grammatically correct choice. If Bob became a girl and then we made a sentence about *him* then we would use *she* instead.

> If Bob was a girl he would run. Bob was magically turned into a girl. Bob is running now, as she thought she would.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely "he". We are still talking about **Bob** as he's a male.